# How to set application layout in plugin controller in cakephp 3.x?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am new to cakephp 3 and I don't know how to add our application layout to specific plugin controller.

My folder structure like below:

```
<pre>
projectName(folder)
->Plugins(folder)
  ->PluginsName
   ->src
    ->controller
     ->UsersController
->src(folder)
  ->Template(folder)
    ->Layout(folder)
      ->login.ctp
</pre>
```

How can I use this `login.ctp` layout in my plugins controller (UsersController)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add layout in specific function by following way.

```
// Set the layout.
$this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('login');

// Before 3.4
$this->viewBuilder()->layout('login');

// Before 3.1
$this->layout = 'login';
```

if you need add it in full controller then you can add it in `beforeRender`

```
public function beforeRender(Event $event)
{
    parent::beforeRender($event);
    $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('Admintheme');
}
```

Ref:  [beforeRender](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#Cake%5CController%5CController::beforeRender) and [Layout](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#layouts)